# Lines Functional values how to shows before saving the record

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

Openerp 7 based on this requirement Sale order lines Remaining days Calculate Start Date minus Today at all times. Functional Field and on_change function used:-

```
def _remaining_days(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    if not ids:
        return {}
    for val in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        result = datetime.datetime.strptime(val.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.datetime.strptime(current_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        res[val.id] = result.days
    return res

'remaining_days': fields.function(_remaining_days, method=True, string='Remaining days', type='integer'),


def onchange_holddays(self, cr, uid, ids, start_date, context=None):
    result = {}  
    context = context or {}
    if release_date:
        current_date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        remaining = datetime.datetime.strptime(release_date, '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.datetime.strptime(current_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        result['remaining_days'] = remaining.days                
    return {'value': result}
```

In order lines Remaining days Values not updated automatically. once save the main sale order record then only lines Remaining days value updated. How to shows the remaining days values in list view before saving the record.
Kno

Answer (score 1):

function field is executed only when you save the record, so you'll not be able to get those values before that. Either use On_change event and display values on run time or use a wizard to accept such data and save it on main form.